# problem trying to initialize and set component state with this axios/typescript implementation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm trying to use Axios with TypeScript in a React component.  The following suggested answer in a different thread seems to provide some pretty good guidance:

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1510#issuecomment-385939438

However, something about the suggested approach doesn't appear to be translating well for my component implementation.  After fiddling around with this implementation, it seems that I'm still unclear on how state should be initialized in the constructor for this scenario, and possibly within the request().then() handler as well.  Here's my current code:

https://github.com/git-it-2020/random/blob/master/axios-react-typescript

The code is fairly simple but doesn't currently compile.  Can you provide some guidance on what I'm missing here?